# Copying a dynamic home directory to a new drive

Tags: directory, home-directory

I am running a weather-based web-server using Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS.  Recently the 2TB drive that runs the OS (/dev/sdb) started producing disk-error messages.  There were (2) 2TB drives in the server but only one was in use - the other (/dev/sda) was damaged during formatting.  I removed the damaged /sda drive  and installed a new 2TB drive in its place and did a "dd" to clone sdb to the new sda.  When that completed some 10 hours later, I found that the server was still working, now on the new sda drive.  I pulled sdb and replaced it with another new 2TB drive and loaded Ubuntu 15.10 into it from a CD.

My question is:  how can I copy my /home directory to the new sdb drive?  The /home directory gets updated about every 5 seconds from weather software 
running on a Win XP machine and ftp'd to the server.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not possible take the system offline for a few hours to just copy files without hurry, I would do something like this:

- copy the old `/home` to the new location using the "archive" mode of `cp` command: `cp -a /old/home /new/home`. The external process may still continue to add files to the "old home".
- make the changes to `/etc/fstab` so the "new home" is mounted on boot
- reboot. On boot the "new home" will be mounted but it's possible that some recent files are missing. The system is online again and the external process start uploading files to the "new home"
- use rsync to copy the missing files from the "old home" to the "new home":   `rsync -av /old/home /new/home`

The above scenario assumes that the external process *uploads* new files every few seconds but does not modify/override the any existing files.

(all shell commands from the top of my head, treat as pseudocode)

Comment: Sergey, it sounds like that would work - the only question I have is how do I tell the cp command that /new/home is on /dev/sdb?

Comment: You create a directory somewhere and mount the drive there temporarily: "mkdir -p /new/home; mount /dev/sdb1 /new/home" (note that there are usually partitions on your hard drive, and you want to mount a partition. /dev/sdb is the whole drive while /dev/sdb1 is a partition)